# Minimum AWG of a battery wire

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistance, amperage

I have a 3.7V one-cell polymer battery 350mAh 25C. It's linked to a board over a 50mm wire. What would be a good AWG diameter to ensure a maximum voltage drop inferior to 2%?

Comment: 25C * 350mAh = 5.25A. 3.7V * 0.02 / 5.25A = 14mohm

Comment: what current does your board require?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I think "25C" is a reference to temperature. OP, if so, try putting `&deg;` in front of the C.

Comment: @DaveTweed: It's true that 25C might be a stretch for a single cell, but it may in fact just be a 1S battery instead.

Comment: Yes, it's 25C. The board can draw between 2A and 3A.

Comment: On a similar device, I saw 1mm-diameter wires but I would like to estimate if it's too big or not. 1mm is around 18 AWG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum AWG depends on the current, which you did not specify. There is no minimum AWG, but it would be a bit silly to use 0000 (4/0) wire for a small battery.

It also good to have a wire that is physically robust, so AWG 20 to 24, maybe 28 are reasonable. The maximum ampacity also should not be exceeded.

Assuming 50mm (100mm round trip), then you wish the maximum voltage drop to be 0.02*3.7 = 74mV. Referring to a [wire table](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) we can determine the maximum current for each wire gauge. Resistance for 0.1m is 3.3/5.3/8.4m\$\Omega\$ for AWG 20/22/24 wire. Refer to [this](http://www.coonerwire.com/amp-chart/) table for ampacity,

So the maximum current would be limited by wire ampacity, and you should just select a wire that is physically robust unless your current is very high.

Comment: The board can draw between 2A and 3A.

Comment: On a similar device, I saw 1mm-diameter wires but I would like to estimate if it's too big or not. 1mm is around 18 AWG

Comment: 1mm/AWG18 seems like excessively heavy wire for 3A. 2.1m\$\Omega\$ for 100mm which would drop only 6.3mV, and you're allowing 74mV. Even with AWG 24 wire (which is pretty flimsy) you'd only have 25mV of drop.